# How to determine horizontal and vertical extents in device units with SetViewportExtEx() and printer?

Tags: winapi, printing, gdi

I am experimenting with using the Windows GDI API for printing and have been doing a few experiments to attempt to understand the translation and how window and viewport extents work.

Examples I have found are using `GetDeviceCaps()` to get the HORZRES and VERTRES dimensions (despite the known fact they can be unreliable and inaccurate) and then using these values with `SetViewportExtEx()` however they divide the values returned by `GetDeviceCaps()` by two.

Why is the `cxpage` and the `cypage` values halved and how can I predict the values to use and the effect on the printed output? Is this due to using `MM_ISOTROPIC` as the mapping mode?

Examples use something like the following code:

```
int cxpage = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, HORZRES);
int cypage = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, VERTRES);
SetMapMode (hDC, MM_ISOTROPIC);
SetWindowExtEx(hDC, 1500, 1500, NULL);
SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);
SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, 0, 0, NULL);
```

In my actual test program I have the following function to print a page when my main Windows message handler sees the message `IDM_PRINT` generated when the user selects Print from the File menu of the test application. The handler uses `PrintDlg()` to get a handle to a Device Context (hDC) then calls this function to exercise the printing.

```
int PrintMyPages (HDC hDC)
{
    int cxpage = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, HORZRES);
    int cypage = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, VERTRES);

    // When MM_ISOTROPIC mode is set, an application must call the
    // SetWindowExtEx function before it calls SetViewportExtEx. Note that
    // for the MM_ISOTROPIC mode certain portions of a nonsquare screen may
    // not be available for display because the logical units on both axes
    // represent equal physical distances.
    SetMapMode (hDC, MM_ISOTROPIC);

    // Since mapping mode is MM_ISOTROPIC we need to specify the extents of the
    // window and the viewport we are using to see the window in order to establish
    // the proper translation between window and viewport coordinates.
    SetWindowExtEx(hDC, 1500, 1500, NULL);
    SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);
    SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, 0, 0, NULL);

    // figure out the page size in logical units for the loop that is printing
    // out the pages of output. we must do this after setting up our window and
    // viewport extents so Windows will calculate the DPtoLP() for the specified
    // translation correctly.
    RECT pageRect = {0};
    pageRect.right = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, HORZRES);
    pageRect.bottom = GetDeviceCaps (hDC, VERTRES);
    DPtoLP(hDC, (LPPOINT)&pageRect, 2);

    // create my font for drawing the text to be printed and select it into the DC for printing.
    HFONT DisplayFont = CreateFont (166, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, false, false, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                                      OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
                                      DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, _T("Arial Rounded MT Bold"));
    HGDIOBJ hSave = SelectObject (hDC, DisplayFont);

    POINT ptLine = {300, 200};  // our printer line cursor for where printing should start.

    static DOCINFO di = { sizeof (DOCINFO), TEXT ("INVOICE TABLE : Printing...")};
    StartDoc (hDC, &di);
    StartPage (hDC);

    for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        TCHAR xBuff[256] = {0};
        swprintf (xBuff, 255, _T("This is line %d of my text."), i);
        TextOut (hDC, ptLine.x, ptLine.y, xBuff, _tcslen(xBuff));
        // get the dimensions of the text string in logical units so we can bump cursor to next line.
        SIZE  lineSize = {0};
        GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, xBuff, _tcslen(xBuff), &lineSize);
        ptLine.y += lineSize.cy;    // bump the cursor down to the next line of the printer. X coordinate stays the same.
        if (ptLine.y + lineSize.cy > pageRect.bottom) {
            // reached the end of this page so lets start another.
            EndPage (hDC);
            StartPage (hDC);
            ptLine.y = 200;
        }
    }

    // end the final page and then end the document so that physical printing will start.
    EndPage (hDC);
    EndDoc (hDC);

    // Release the font object that we no longer need.
    SelectObject (hDC, hSave);
    DeleteObject (DisplayFont);

    return 1;
}
```

When I modify the call of `SetViewportExtEx()` from `SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);` (output on the right in the image below) to `SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage, cypage, NULL);` (output on the left in the image below) the printed text seems almost double in height and width.

[image]

**Additional Notes on Extents and Mapping Modes**

Charles Petzold Programming Windows 5th Edition (Chapter 5 - Basic Drawing, page 180) writes:

> The formulas also include two points that specify "extents": the point
>   (*xWinExt*, *yWinExt*) is the window extent in logical coordinates;
>   (*xViewExt*, *yViewExt*) is the viewpoort extent in device
>   coordinates. In most mapping modes, the extents are implied by the
>   mapping mode and cannot be changed. Each extent means nothing by
>   itself, but the ratio of the viewport extent to the window extent is a
>   scaling factor for converting logical units to device units.
>
> For example, when you set the MM_LOENGLISH mapping mode, Windows sets
>   *xViewExt* to be a certain number of pixels and *xWinExt* to be the length in hundredths of an inch occupied by *xViewExt* pixels. The
>   ratio gives you pixels per hundredths of an inch. The scaling factors
>   are expressed as ratios of integers rather than floating point values
>   for performance reasons.

Petzold then goes on to discuss `MM_ISOTROPIC` and `MM_ANISOTROPIC` on page 187.

> The two remaining mapping modes are named `MM_ISOTROPIC` and
>   `MM_ANISOTROPIC`. These are the only two mapping modes for which
>   Windows lets you change the viewport and window extents, which means
>   that you can change the scaling factor that Windows uses to translate
>   logical and device coordinates. The word *isotropic* means "equal in
>   all directions"; *anisotropic* is the opposite - "not equal." Like the
>   metric mapping modes shown earlier, `MM_ISOTROPIC` uses equally scaled
>   axes. Logical units on the x-axis have the same physical dimensions as
>   logical units on the y-axis. This helps when you need to create images
>   that retain the correct aspect ratio regardless of the aspect ratio of
>   the display device.
>
> The difference between `MM_ISOTROPIC` and the metric mapping modes is
>   that with `MM_ISOTROPIC` you can control the physical size of the
>   logical unit. If you want, you can adjust the size of the logical unit
>   based on the client area. This lets you draw images that are always
>   contained within the client area, shrinking and expanding
>   appropriately. The two clock programs in Chapter 8 have isotropic
>   images. As you size the window, the clocks are resized appropriately.
>
> A Windows program can handle the resizing of an image entirely through
>   adjusting the window and viewport extents. The program can then use
>   the same logical units in the drawing functions regardless of the size
>   of the window.

Comment: In my (very) limited experience, it's far easier not to monkey about with `MM_ISOTROPIC` mode. Since paper sizes are known in advance, I find it far easier to simply work in millimetres (you can just as easily use inches). Here's a link to the test-code I worked with when implementing printing for the first time. It prints a page to a pdf-writing 'printer', using A4 paper (I think this is because the printer's default is A4, its been a long time and I forget). The very edge of the page gets a red border and there is another 10mm in from the edge of the page. The logo is ~ 44x22 mm. (no ruler)

Comment: (cont)
Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/tSLMJpSb - The size of 44x22 is as reported by the code. I don't have access to a printer or a ruler at the present time, though the image does indeed appear to be about 10% higher than the distance from the edge of the page to the edge of the image, which should be 20mm.

Comment: @enhzflep thank you for the code example. I do not see where you are setting the mapping mode so I assume it is using some default. Do you know what that is? Your test program appears to be creating a series of drawn rectangles. With my test program using only text, perhaps I should use a mapping mode of MM_TEXT instead? However that would require counting device pixels and the WinAPI primitives seem to be designed for logical units. Perhaps MM_ISOTROPIC and MM_ANISOTROPIC are meant for plotters? Would MM_TWIPS be best for text?

Comment: If I change the call to `SetWindowExtEx()` to use `SetWindowExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);` rather than the hard coded `1500` the page printed on my Laserjet 4200 has all 29 print lines on one page and the text is smaller as well. I interpret this to mean that since `SetWindowExtEx()` and `SetViewportExtEx()` have the same extents there is no scaling being done as there is a one to one translation from page coordinate space to device coordinate space per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145139(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @enhzflep I am reading Charles Petzold Programming Windows 5th Edition which on page 141 has a table describing the default Device Context (DC) values. Mapping Mode default is MM_TEXT.

Comment: I'll have to look at my copy of the same book when I return home and get back to you. I seem to recall having answered another question either here or elsewhere that was concerned with maximising the size of text to fit within an arbitrarily sized table cell. I imagine that thread has some goodies in it you may find helpful. From memory, the username of the other fella was `AlwaysLearningNewStuff`. I'll have a look for that thread too.

Comment: @enhzflep I think that we have answered part of my question and what was puzzling me about the difference in size between the two versions of arguments to the `SetWindowExtEx()` function. I think the last remaining question is why do so many examples use `SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);` where `cxpage` and `cypage` are `GetDeviceCaps (hDC, HORZRES)` and `GetDeviceCaps (hDC, VERTRES)` respectively. Is this to scale the output by a factor of two for some reason? What would that reason be? Perhaps just a habit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... why do so many examples use `SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);` where cxpage and cypage are `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES)` and `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES)` respectively[?]

I suspect MM_ISOTROPIC is often used for plotting graphs where the origin would be in the center of the page rather than the corner.  If we took your code and tweaked it to move the origin to the center of the printable region, like this:

```
SetWindowExtEx(hDC, 1500, 1500, NULL);
SetViewportExtEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);
SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, cxpage/2, cypage/2, NULL);
```

Then you could plot using logical coordinates that range from -1500 to +1500.  (You might also want to flip the sign of one of the y-extents to get positive "up".)

For textual output, I don't see any advantage to halving the viewport extents and I would keep the origin in the upper left.

Comment: Yes, everyone seems to copy Petzold with cxPage/2 etc. (E.g. see Figure 13-6 in his book.)